# How to setting input position with border:solid transparent

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

In my project, I got a problem for CSS define.

I want Jack,Tom,shansa and Stack in the same horizontal line, like:

```
  Jack Tom Shansa Stack
```

But Jack should be binded with file input, and it's css definition is different from others.

Here is css and html code:

```css
.upBtDiv {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  /*display: inline;*/
  top: 8px
}

.upBtDiv a {
  cursor: pointer
}

.upBtDiv input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: solid transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<table border="2px" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:85%" colspan="10">
      <div style="padding:5px" id="attFId">
        <div class="upBtDiv">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="fUpl()" data-options="iconCls:'icon-newfile'">Jack</a>
          <input type="file" id="iT">
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" data-options="iconCls:'icon-more'">Tom</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" data-options="iconCls:'icon-cancel'">Shansa</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" data-options="iconCls:'icon-tip'">Stack</a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now, Jack is level above others. like:

```
         Jack
              Tom Shansa Stack
```

I have tried to add top:8px in input style and a style, but it worked fail.

And I changed top:8px to padding :5px  of upBtDiv style, and it failed again.

It seems nothing wrong, but I don't know how to setting position of Jack.

Who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete

```
.upBtDiv a {cursor: pointer}//delete, and works ok
```

Answer (score -1):

Use`vertical-align: middle;`  on the upBtDiv

Without vertical-align:middle;
[image]

With vertical-align: middle;[image]

If you're still having issues with please state which browser you are using. You could also try turning off the position: relative;

Comment: .upBtDiv{position:relative;overflow:hidden;display:inline-block;*display:inline;vertical-align:middle},  works fail